# user defined messages in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g

hai everyone ijust wanted to know how to display a usr defined message in oracle 10g....

Comment: I'm not following the question.  Do you mean that you want to throw a user-defined exception with a custom message?  If so, use the `raise_application_error` procedure.

Comment: then what about system.message_level();

Comment: What about it?  Are you building an Oracle Forms application? If so, that's not apparent from your question or your tags.